# How to Insert a Longbinary field in MS-Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table like that:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Image (IdImage TEXT(5) NOT NULL, Image LONGBINARY NULL)
```

In Sql Server is possible to perform this insert:

```sql
INSERT Image (IdImage, Image) VALUES ('ESPL', 0x89504E470D0A1A0A0000000D494844520000012C0000012C08030000004EA3753)
```

Is there a way to perform this insert in ms-Access?

Comment: What attempts have you made? What did you try?

Comment: As far as I know Access does not have a Longbinary data type.

Comment: Access has OLEObject and Attachment field types. You should explore those for storing image files.